# Wire service in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter to add authentication detail

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want add custom data to Authentication object in security authentication process:

```
public class MyAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    MyUserDetailService userDetailService;  // <==== How to wire??

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        ...
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
               username,
               r.sessionId,
               Arrays.asList(new GrantedAuthority[]{new SimpleGrantedAuthority(grantedUserRole)}));
        auth.setDetails(userDetailService.getDetail()); // <== Save detail to auth.
        return auth;
    }
}
```

How can I wire MyUserDetailService service?

How can I cache MyUserDetailService to principal mapping (in order to avoid unnecessary call `userDetailService.getDetail()` and don't fall with out of memory)?

**PS** `spring-security.xml`:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="oauthEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="oauthAuthenticationManager">
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <anonymous username="anonymous" enabled="true" granted-authority="AN" key="anonymous-security" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="com.web.filter.MyAuthFilter"> ...</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security follow usual Spring architecture, so my custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is just plain bean.

I don't need to mark class as `@Component` as it declared in `spring-security.xml`. And I may use:

```
 @Autowired
 private UserService userService;
```

or:

```
public class MyAuthFilter
extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private UserService userService;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        userService = applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);
    }
...
}
```

After placing value of userDetailService.getDetail() to authentication:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    userName, sessionId,
    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(grantedUserRole));     
auth.setDetails(userService.get(userName));
```

it will be automatically cached as session hold association to authentication object and after session invalidation this association will be passed to GC.